# How do I create text with different colors

Tags: java, slick2d

I currently use this line:

```
font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, height, "Hi, Stackoverflow!", Color.yellow);
```

However, that only allows for me to use one colour per message.

Whereas, I would like to have a line like this:

```
font.drawString(Display.getWidth()/2 - offset, height, BLUE TEXT HERE + "Team A score: " + score + RED TEXT HERE + " || " + YELLOW TEXT HERE + "Team B score: " + score, Color.yellow);
```

The variable `font` is of type `UnicodeFont`.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static void setUpFonts() {
    java.awt.Font awtFont = new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", java.awt.Font.BOLD, 18);
    font = new UnicodeFont(awtFont);
    font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.white));
    font.addAsciiGlyphs();
    try {
        font.loadGlyphs();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        cleanUp();
    }
}
```

Would be nice if there was a solution that did not require multiple messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, there is no such method.**

You will have to split it up like:

```
g.setColor(Color.blue);
g.drawString("Hi,", 50, 50);

g.setColor(Color.red);
g.drawString("Stackoverflow!", 50 + font.getWidth("Hi, "), 50);
```

What you can do as a workaround is to write yourself a helper method that does all the calculation and handling of the offsets if you need it more often. Something like:

```
public void drawString(Graphics g, int x, int y, Object... args)
{
    org.newdawn.slick.Font font = g.getFont();
    int currentOffset = x;
    int startOffset = x;

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length / 2; i++)
    {
        g.setColor((Color) args[i * 2]);
        g.drawString((String) (args[i * 2 + 1]), currentOffset, y);

        currentOffset += font.getWidth(((String) (args[i * 2 + 1])));

        if (((String) (args[i * 2 + 1])).contains("\n"))
        {
            currentOffset = startOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
drawString(g, 10, 10, "Stack", Color.red, "Overflow", Color.green, "!", Color.yellow);
```

Comment: Where does this g.drawString come from?? What is a "Graphics"?

Comment: @Joehot200 Graphics is the graphics context in Slick2D and g is an instance of it. g.drawString(..) is a method in Graphics that draws a String at a specified location with the current font.